# AutoMapper - Map using the same source and destination object types

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper to take two objects of the same type and map any new values that have changed. I tried using the code below, but it keeps throwing an error and I'm not even sure if this can even be achieved with Automapper.

For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDetails, UserDetails>();
UserDetails userDetails = Mapper.Map<UserDetails, UserDetails>(userDetailsCurrent, userDetailsNew);
```

Basically, I need to copy across any new values that come in from the new object `userDetailsNew` to the existing object `userDetailsCurrent` - even though they are of the same type. This way I can "update" the existing object with the new values. The reason I am doing this is because I am not sure what user details will be passed in - I need to map them as and when they arrive.

I have normally used Automapper to map different objects with similar properties - but I thought that I could use the power of Automapper to achieve the same thing this way. There might even be a better solution - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should `Mapper.Map` return a `UserDetails` or a `UserSession`?

Comment: It should return UserDetails  - Ive just updated the code sample.

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Answer (score 15):

This is a known behavior of Automapper ([see issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/656)). You actually have to tell Automapper:

> ```
> CreateMap<A,A>();
> CreateMap<B,B>();
> CreateMap<C,C>();
> ```

Comment: Explanation: you must explicitly create a new map that maps a type to the same type so AutoMapper has a map to use.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work for me.  My custom type:

```
class MyType
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyType, MyType>();
var source = new MyType() {MyInt = 1, MyString = "Hello world"};
var dest = Mapper.Map<MyType, MyType>(source);
```

What is interesting about your custom type beyond simple properties?

Comment: This looks good - Im not near my PC so Ill check this and get back ASAP!

Comment: Is there a way that I can do it without using ForMember()? It might be cleaner to not do that for each property on the Object.

Comment: Yeah, it still works if you don't do ForMember.  I am just so used to using those that I included it initially.

Comment: Almost there, but is there a way that allows me to keep the existing values on the destination object. Such as "UserDetails userDetails = Mapper.Map<UserDetails, UserDetails>(userDetailsCurrent, userDetailsNew);" When I try that it throws an error. I need to keep the existing values and map in any new values that come in.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done using tuples and by creating a custom type converter deriving from Automapper's Abstract TypeConverter class.

Say you had a source and destination class of:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Firstname: {0}, Lastname: {1}", FirstName, LastName);
    }
}
```

Then you could build the custom converter type as

```
public class CustomerPersonConverter : TypeConverter<Tuple<Person, Person>, Person>
{
    protected override Person ConvertCore(Tuple<Person, Person> source)
    {
        var orginalValues = source.Item1;
        var updatedValues = source.Item2;

        var result = new Person
            {
                FirstName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(updatedValues.FirstName) ? orginalValues.FirstName : updatedValues.FirstName,
                LastName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(updatedValues.LastName) ? orginalValues.LastName : updatedValues.LastName
            };

        return result;
    }
}
```

which could be used like

```
var orginal = new Person() {FirstName = "Clifford", LastName = "Mayson"};
        var updated = new Person() {FirstName = "Cliff"};

        Mapper.CreateMap<Tuple<Person, Person>, Person>().ConvertUsing<CustomerPersonConverter>();

        var result = Mapper.Map<Person>(new Tuple<Person, Person>(orginal, updated));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which would produce the result of keeping the original last name value as that was missing in the update but updating the firstname value eg.

```
Firstname: Cliff, Lastname: Mayson
```